# Correlated binary variables with heterogeneous marginal probabilities

Tags: r, correlation

I would like to create 50 correlated binary variables where different variables have different marginal probabilities:

First I create my correlation matrix:

```
cor.mat=matrix(.9,nrow=50,ncol=50)
cor.mat[,9:11]=.1 
cor.mat[9:11,]=.1  
diag(cor.mat)=1
```

Then I generate the data using 'rmvbin':

```
library(bindata)
marg=rep(c(0.4,0.6),c(25,25))
a<-rmvbin(100, margprob=marg, bincorr=cor.mat)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) : 
  Matrix commonprob not admissible.
```

I have also tried with commonprob instead of margprob:

```
common=rep(c(0.4,0.6),c(25,25))
a<-rmvbin(100, commonprob=common, bincorr=cor.mat)
```

but I get:

```
Error in if (n != dim(commonprob)[2]) { : argument is of length zero
>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

### Change the ".9" to ".4" or lower

```
cor.mat=matrix(0.4, nrow=50, ncol=50)
cor.mat[,9:11]=.1 
cor.mat[9:11,]=.1  
diag(cor.mat)=1
```

### This should now run:

```
library(bindata)
marg=rep(c(0.4,0.6),c(25,25))
a<-rmvbin(100, margprob=marg, bincorr=cor.mat)
```

### for the second error:

#### 1. `commonprob` needs to be a matrix.

#### 2. Only one of the arguments `commonprob`, `bincorr` and `sigma` may be specified. Default are uncorrelated components.

```
m <- cbind(c(1/2,1/5,1/6),c(1/5,1/2,1/6),c(1/6,1/6,1/2))
m
check.commonprob(m)
rmvbin(10,commonprob=m)
## or
## same as the example above, but faster if the same probabilities are
## used repeatedly (commonprob2sigma rather slow)
sigma <- commonprob2sigma(m)
rmvbin(10,margprob=diag(m),sigma=sigma)
```

source:  examples from help file for rmvbin